# Three different diminished scales?

Tags: scales

I'm reading about some jazz stuff, and get told there are ony two whole tone scales, and three diminished scales. The whole tones are pretty obvious - once you get past the second semitone, you're into a mode of the original one. But - I thought there were the whole/half and the half/whole diminished scales, so what's the third one?  Unless the writer conflated scales and arpeggios, whereby the notes of say, Co, C♯o and Do are all different, but when we arrive at E♭o, that's a mode of the first, Co?

Comment: whole + half = 3 half steps.  If a pattern repeats every 3 half steps, it can only have 3 versions. 
 Proof: the one starting on C goes C, D, Eb F Gb.  Now look at the one starting on Eb, and you'll see it's the same collection of notes.  The other way to look at it is C has 2 of them, but one of them doesn't have a C at all.

Comment: They mean the somewhat abstract observation regarding counting scales as a *set* of pitch classes.  So, up to starting note, there are only two distinct whole tone scales: 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10; and 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11.  Similarly, there are only three distinct diminished scales up to starting note: 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10; 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11; and 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11.

Answer (score 7):

There are three unique whole-half (or half-whole) diminished scales starting a half-step apart from each other. Each one has an equivalent half-whole (or whole-half) diminished scale starting a whole step (or half step) above it.

```
Equivalences between whole-half and half-whole diminished scales

Whole-Half scale | Half-Whole scale
starting pitch   | starting pitch
-------------------------------------
C, Eb, Gb, or A  | D, F, Ab, or B
C#, E, G, or Bb  | C, Eb, Gb, or A
D, F, Ab, or B   | C#, E, G, or Bb
```

Comment: So doesn't that make **six** different diminished scales..?

Comment: Simple, really, innit?

Comment: @Tim Another way to look at it is that W-H and H-W are two different scales, and there are three unique versions of each. In that way it's like saying there are 12 major scales and 12 (natural) minor scales, even though they only differ according to their starting pitches.

Comment: Thanks. I was considering that the writer (a certain Jamie) was considering a diminished seventh arp. as a scale - when there wuld in fact be three different ones - and their modes.

Comment: Calling H/W and W/H the "same" is like say phrygian and lydian are the same, because they are rotations of the diatonic scale.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis My language was sloppy. Just for my clarification, are you commenting on my answer, or my comment?

Comment: The comment. But, the way I would put it is there is one major scale (structure) and one natural minor, both can be transposed to 12 tonics. Both can be found in rotations of the other. They aren't the same for being rotations of one set, but different for the different intervals above a tonic.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Thanks for pointing it out. I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 5):

> only two whole tone scales, and three diminished scales.

They just mean that when you account from transposing the scales there are only 2 *unique sets of tones* for the whole tone scale, and 3 for a diminished scale.

But they are overlooking there are *two* diminished (or octatonic) scales.

In terms of interval structure there is *one* whole tones scale - all whole steps, and *two* octatonic scales - one alternating whole and half steps, the other alternating half and whole steps.

When you transpose a whole tone scale by a whole tone, you get the same set of tones.

When you transpose a diminished/octatonic scale by a minor third, you get the same set of tones.

If you take the rotations, or modes, of the scales instead of transpose them, something funny happens. All rotations of a whole tone scale produce the same set of tones just like transposing by a whole step. But, with the diminished scale, every other rotation produced the same set of tones or the "opposite" diminished scale, for example take second rotation of a W/H diminished scale and you get a H/W diminished scale.

If, for some reason, you treat the first and second rotation of a diminished scale to be the same thing, then there are only 3 diminished scales.

If you treat octatonic scales as just embellishments of a diminished seventh chord, then I guess it sort of makes sense to treat W/H and H/W as the same.

If you realize that W/H octatonic has a perfect *fourth* above the tonic, and H/W has diminished sixth - enharmonically equivalent to a perfect *fifth* -  that's a significant structural difference, and W/H and H/W are different scales. With H/W you can construct major, minor, and diminished triads above the tonic.

Coincidentally, I recently was looking at my scale syllabus from a certain Jamey, for a dominant seventh flat nine chord. He gives the diminished scale, but only the H/W version. That makes sense, because it provides the flat nine. But, that also underscores the two diminished scales are *not* necessary to be treated as the same.

Comment: I think it's the way he phrased the whole thing. There were a couple of other iffily phrased bits too. Producing 'educational' documents, I feel it's of paramount importance to eliminate all statements which may, even in the least, be construed as ambiguous.

Comment: I find a lot of jazz pedagogy unclear and, at least for me, prompts lots of follow up questions. It's almost always confusion about _the wording and terminology_.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I’m concerned there are 12 whole tone scales, 12 W/H diminished scales and 12 H/W diminished scales. The two diminished scales I mentioned are separate entities. I’ve never agreed with the “there are only 2 whole tone scales” etc. explanation. Of course several of the scales share notes but I approach them as individual entities. Just as I don’t think of E Phrygian as a C scale from E to E I don’t think of a E whole tone scale as a C whole tone scale from E to E. The tonal center of a scale should have some importance, even if it shares notes with 4 or 6 other scales.

Based on his logic of “only 2 whole tone scales”, the writer is definitely thinking of a single diminished scale in 3 chromatic positions, C, C#, D and saying everything else just comes from there.

Comment: We may be getting into the realm of 'when is a mode a scale, when is a scale a mode' territory...

Comment: @Tim I’d say pretty much always in both cases…

Comment: I can't make up my mind - a scale is a set of notes put into an order - ascending/descending. But Dorian, Phrygian, Lydian, etc., are almost always referred to as *modes*.  To me, a mode is an inversion of a known (accepted) scale. A question may be coming on...

Comment: @Tim Everyone brace yourselves!